# How can I hide the picture preview?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new in iPhone development, 
I have built new app to take a picture using `UIImagePickerController`.
Everything is work fine with me, but I need to dismiss the picture preview that appear after I press the capture button.
I search through the net then I found I must use the following routine.

```
(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo 
{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

but it didn't work.

Any help or suggestions, is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your own camera overlay view.  This view should have a button on to Take a picture.

To add an overlay view, create a view with a background colour of clear, then assign your overlay view to the picker control

```
   self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
   self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = myOverlayView;
```

Then in your overlay view button event you call the following:

```
 [imagePickerController takePicture];
```

This will then fire the following method on the imagePickerDelegate, and you can save your photo etc in there

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Comment: thank you for reply I have read some articles regards overlay, but I didn't understand it clearly. Can you lead me to good example?

Comment: I used the following tutorial when I was first looking into it. http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=821